# GeoDjango on AWS Elastic Beanstalk: OSError: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, geodjango

Trying to run GeoDjango on Amazon Linux 2.9.5 Elastic Beanstalk. I had to compile GDAL from source and install it into usr/local/gdal, along with proj4 and geos, this was done using this [script](https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example/blob/master/gdal-build-script.sh). This fixed my original issue of not having GDAL installed, but now I am confronted with this error:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 343, in __init__
 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
`OSError: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

The error is occuring when Django tries to run GeoDjango at this [line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86908785076b2bbc31b908781da6b6ad1779b18b/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py#L46). It could have something to do with the C compiler on Amazon Linux?

I can't seem to find that libcrypto.so.1.1 file. I was only able to find the following:

**Location: /usr/lib64/**

```
libcrypto.so                       
libcrypto.so.10         
libcrypto.so.1.0.2k         
libcrypt.so
```

**Location: /lib64/**
    libcrypt.so.1

Libcrypto.so.1.1 is not installed on this EC.